# Tortoise git Asking password on every pull and push operation

Tags: ssh, putty, tortoisegit

I have added a key also.

I tried adding username and password in url as: root:password@ssh://10.10.14.119//home/pk/user_app.git.

I tried making file containing login and password and added that from windows 10 cmd prompt.

Nothing is working. Its asking password for every push and pull

Comment: I already told that I've tried keys, please go through full description above

Comment: and did you add it to git server?

Comment: plz help.............

Comment: So then you have the logs from client and server where you see why it does fail. `ssh -vvv root@10.10.14.119` works? If you provide the key as `ssh -vvvi /path/to/key root@10.10.14.119`?

Comment: yes, Its telling that authentication of 10.10.14.119 can't be established

Comment: Do you use openssh or tortoisegitplink?

Comment: ssh.exe and tortoisegitplink both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses.
Finally I got the answer.

**I used the global key (id_rsa.ppk) of my git server and its working very well now.**

Comment: Reinstalling Git also helps